# Fourier transform from Laplace transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, laplace-transform

So what I did was Laplace transform $f(t)$ to $F(s)$ and then plug in $s=jw$.
However, when I tried this for $cos(3t)$, $$F(jw)={jw\over9-w^2}$$
was the answer. I don't know if this is correct, and I'm not satisfied since I would intuitively expect dirac functions at w=3 and -3.
Could anyone clarify what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: [See this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Fourier_transform) (which discusses exactly your problem)

Comment: Cool! At least I know Wikipedia supports my answer. Though I'm still somewhat concerned about the fact that my answer has magnitude greater than zero when w is not 3...

Comment: Did you read the full section? "As $s = iω$ is a pole of $F(s)$, substituting $s = iω$ in $F(s)$ ${\bf does~not}$ yield the Fourier transform of $f(t)u(t)$, which is proportional to the Dirac delta-function $δ(ω-ω0)$".

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That helped me quite a bit.